# Javascript loop through months and years

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm wondering how to create single loop for create variable between today and start date.

```
var startDate = 11-15; /*that means 11th month of 2015*/

var d = new Date();
var m = d.getMonth() + 1;
var y = d.getFullYear().toString().substr(-2);

for (var i = 11; i <= m; i++) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

Result should be 11-15, 12-15, 1-16 and so on until today 9-17. I don't know how I can add year into my code.

Comment: For starters, I recommend you use a date library such as moment.js. You'll be thankful you did.

Comment: A hint: 11-15 is an integer calculation that produces -4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming startdate is a string you can use below code

```
var startDate = "11-15"

var d = new Date();
var m = d.getMonth() + 1;
var y = d.getFullYear().toString().substr(-2);
d=startDate.split("-")
counter = parseInt(d[0])
for(var i=parseInt(d[1]);i<=parseInt(y);i++)
{
  for(var j=counter;j<=12;j++){
    if(j>m && i==y){
       continue
    }
    console.log(j+"-"+i)
  }
  counter = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use `.split()` over `startDate` which should be a `string`, and extract `month` and `year` and keep incrementing them respectively until you reach `09-17`:

```js
var startDate = "11-15";

var month = parseInt(startDate.split("-")[0]);
var year = parseInt(startDate.split("-")[1]);

var results = [];

while(!(year === 17 && month === 9)){
  if(month<12){
    month++;
  }else{
     month = 1;
     year++;
  }
  console.log(month+'-'+year);
  results.push(month+'-'+year);
}

console.log(results);
```